# Vuejs array push

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm receiving array of objects from backend in below format. I am trying to get this data and push it into a JavaScript array so that I can use them later on based on my needs.

```
[
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "Dr. Darrin Frami III",
    email: "darrin67@example.com",
    address: "42568 Cameron Cove Fritschborough, MA 86432-0749",

    },
]
```

Here is my vuejs code:

```
<script>
    export default {
      data(){
        return {
          fakeUsers: [],
          fakeUser: {id: '', name: '', email: ''},
        } 
      },
      methods:{

      },
        mounted() {
            var route = '/get-users';
            this.$http.get(route).then((response)=>{
              for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                 this.fakeUser.id = response.data[i].id;
                 this.fakeUser.name = response.data[i].name;
                 this.fakeUser.email = response.data[i].email;
                 this.fakeUsers.push(this.fakeUser);
              }

            });
            console.log(this.fakeUsers);
            console.log(this.fakeUsers[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

the vue-dev tool result:

[image]

Output of the line  `console.log(this.fakeUsers);` is `[__ob__: Observer]`. Shouldn't it print something like `[Array[10]]`?

Output of the line `console.log(this.fakeUsers[0]);` is `undefined`, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$http() creates an async ajax call, so the code in `then()` is executed *after* the console command after it.

Simple solution: put the console commands into the function in `.then()` as well.

Comment: excellent answer mate.. but i need to know one more thing.. as im new with vuejs.. and have not finished reading all documentations yet. just watched some tutorials. but i have one query, how can i get the first element after the ajax call is complete when the page loads? @linus